# Google Analytics API - How to generate traffic source summary?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In Google Analytics, if you goto

```
Traffic Sources -> Overview
```

There's a pie chart of the breakdown of % traffic sources.

How do I get this information via the API?

What are the metrics/dimensions?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would seem

```
ga:medium
ge:visits
```

does the trick,

- `(none)` is "direct traffic
- `organic` + `cpc` is search engine
- `referral` is non search engine link

then, the sum of everything else is "campaign"